# Get folder contents using phonegap (android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I know that javascript doesn't allow the browser to get a list of folder contents (client side), but if I'm using phonegap to create android application, is it possible for me to get a list of sub-folders and sub-files of  a certain folder located on the mobile sd (tablet) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using PhoneGap's [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) you can use Javascript to hook into the native file system.